Closed subscheme of projective scheme is projective (ring is not generated in degree $1$)
$\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
Let $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb Z^+$ graded ring (so grading is $n \geq 0$) but which is not necessarilly generated in degree $1$. Let $X=\Proj A$, and $f:Z\rightarrow X$ be a closed immersion. I am trying to show that this implies that $Z$ is isomorphic to $\Proj A/I$ for some homogenous ideal $I$. This has already been asked, with the assumption that $A$ is generated in degree one, here, but I am a bit confused about $a)$ their motivation behind the construction of the ideal, and $b)$ where to go from there.
In my head I feel like a complete proof should go as follows:

Fix an open cover of $X$ by projective distinguished opens $\{U_g\}$, and obtain ideals of $(A_g)_0$ (i.e. the $0$th degree subring of the graded ring $A_g$) via locally identifying $f$ as coming from the quotient map $(A_g)_0\rightarrow (A_g)_0/I_g$.

Using the ideals $\{I_g\}$ construct a homogenous ideal of $J$ of $A$.

Construct an isomorphism from $\Proj A/I$ to $Z$.


So by following the linked post, I construct an ideal $I$ by first taking:
\begin{align}
J_g=\bigoplus_d\{a\in A_d: a^{\deg g}/g^d\in I_g\}
\end{align}
and then set $J=\bigcap_g J_g$. Now, I don't understand the motivation for doing so, the linked post states as follows:

Each of the $I_g$ in $(A_g)_0$ corresponds to a closed subscheme of $U_g$. Then $Z$ is supposed to be the union of these closed subschemes which translates to the intersection of ideals, and hence the result.

However, these closed subscheme are only closed in the subspace topology, and I see no reason why any of them should correspond to a closed subset of $X$ of which $Z$ is supposed to be the union. So even in the degree $1$ case I don't quite get why this what we should do.  From there, I do not understand why working with ideal sheafs is enough to prove the isomorphism to $\Proj A/J$. Regardless, I would still like to construct an explicit isomorphism.
Assuming that this is the correct approach for the case where $A$ is not generated by elements of degree $1$, I would now like to construct my isomorphism $\Proj A/J\rightarrow Z$, and the reason why I want to go this direction is that I know that for $[g],[h]\in A/I$, $U_{[g]}\cap U_{[h]}=U_{[g][h]}$, so the intersections play nice. To do so, I note that I have an open cover $\Proj A/I$ given by $\{U_{[g]}\}$, where the $g$'s are the same as the one from the open cover of $\Proj A$. We also have an open cover over $Z$ by $\{V_g=f^{-1}(U_g)\}$. For any $U_h$ such that $h\in J$, we have that $U_{[h]}$ is empty, and that $h\in J_h$, so $1\in I_h$ and $f^{-1}(U_h)\cong \Spec (A_h)_0/I_h$ must also be empty.
My goal is to now provide ring isomorphisms $(A_g)_0/I_g\rightarrow ((A/J)_{[g]})_0$, and glue them together. So, first and foremost, I have map $A\rightarrow A/J\rightarrow (A/J)_{[g]}$ given by projection, followed by localization. The image of $g$ is a unit under this map, so this gives me a unique map $A_g\rightarrow (A/J)_{[g]}$. If I restrict to the degree zero elements $(A_g)_0$, then since quotients preserve degree, this lands in the degree zero part of $(A/J)_{[g]}$. Now let $a^{\deg g}/g^{\deg a}\in I_g$, then $a\in J$ we have that $a^{\deg g}/g^{\deg a}$ is in the kernel of the map $(A_g)_0\rightarrow (A/J)_{[g]})_0$, so we have a unique  homomorphism $\psi_g:(A_g)_0/I_g\rightarrow (A/J)_{[g]})_0$ given by $[a^{\deg g}/g^{\deg a}]\mapsto [a]^{\deg g}/[g]^{\deg a}$.
However, while this feels like it should be an isomorphism I am unable to prove it. The easiest way seems to be to just provide a ring homomorphism in the other direction, but I am unsure of how to check that any such map would be well defined given that it seems I need a morphism $A\rightarrow (A_g)_0/I_g$ before invoking universal property as otherwise how do elements in $J$ get mapped to zero?
Assuming I had an isomorphism, this would give me isomorphisms $\phi_g:U_{[g]}\rightarrow V_g=f^{-1}(U_g)\subset Z$, but I am unsure of how I could possible check that $\phi_g|_{U_{[g]}\cap U_{[h]}}=\phi_h|_{U_{[g]}\cap U_{[h]}}$.
Any help sorting out this mess would be much appreciated.
Edit: I think it is actually not too hard to show this is injective/surjective directly, so that solves the isomorphism problem. But I’m still confused on how to check that they agree on overlaps.
